# Reduzir tamanho de um Bitmap

Tags: java, android

Como faço para reduzir o tamanho de um Bitmap.Por exemplo, pegar uma foto de 600kB e reduzir para 50KB.

obs:No java.

Comment: Favor poste o informações sobre a imagem, o tamanha máximo que você precisa, a resolução, ou seja seu post precisa de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver problema de OutOfMemory, você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

Este `inSampleSize` reduz a utilização de memória.

Aqui vai o método completo. Primeiro ele lê o tamanho da imagem sem decodificar o conteúdo. Então ele acha o melhor valor para o `inSampleSize`, e finalmente a imagem é decodificada.

```
// Decodifica a imagem e escala para a redução do consumo de memória
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decodifica o tamanho da imagem 
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // O novo tamanho que queremos 
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        // Achar o valor correto para a escala
        int scale = 1;
        while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && 
              o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decodifica com o inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```